# WIX and IIS7: Cannot connect to Internet Information Server. (-2147221164)

Tags: iis, iis-7, wix, wix-iisextension

I have seen
[WiX and iis (cannot connect to internet information server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012572/wix-and-iis-cannot-connect-to-internet-information-server)

This question is different.

I have Windows7, IIS is installed. I'm trying to run an MSI installer built with WIX v3.0 to install an ISAPI filter.

When I run the MSI I get

```
Cannot connect to Internet Information Server.  (-2147221164         )
```

...in the msi log file, and an accompanying error message like `Error 26001.`

In [his response to the other WIX/IIS7 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012572/wix-and-iis-cannot-connect-to-internet-information-server/5013290#5013290), Yan Sklyarenko
said:

> the WiX IIsExtension (the one which defines WebSite element) uses the API of IIS component to actually do its job. For WiX v3.0 it even requires IIS 6 compatibility to be turned ON in IIS 7 in order to work correctly.

I suppose the reason that I saw the error message is that the IIS6 compat stuff is not installed.

Is this pre-requisite still present in Wix v3.5?    In other words, using Wix3.5, must I still have the IIS6 compatibility stuff installed, to use IisExtension ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, WiX v3.5 supports IIS7 directly.

Comment: Lovely! Where is this documented? I looked for release notes but did not find them. I saw the words "Native IIS7 Support" on the release page (http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/60102) but there was no detail or elaboration.

Comment: That's exactly what that means ( no Legacy IIS6 Managment Objects Thunking needed )

Comment: Nothing to elaborate on: The same XML elements are processed for IIS7 if that's what's on the target machine; otherwise, they're processed for IIS5-6.

Answer (score 2):

-2147221164 decimal converts to 0x80040154 hex.  A google search for "wix 0x80040154 brings up the following thread:

[Error 0x80040154: failed to get IID_IIMSAdminBase object with IIS 7](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Error-0x80040154-failed-to-get-IID-IIMSAdminBase-object-with-IIS-7-td3986007.html)

So yes, this error code is a COM registration error associated with the management objects not being present.   The solution is either to gate the installer to not run if they aren't present or upgrade to an installation tool that supports native interaction.